# Присвоить нескольким элементам класс через JS, как?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

В jQuery всё понятно

```
$('.comment-notes, .comment-form-author, .comment-form-email').addClass( "no-height" );
```

А как на чистом js это сделать? Пробовал так, но не работает.

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-notes, .comment-form-author, .comment-form-email")
element.classList.add("no-height");
```

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: Что возвращает `document.querySelectorAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var element of document.querySelectorAll(...)) {
  element.classList.add("no-height");
}
```

Comment: А я хотел навести на `.forEach` :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, ну тоже можно)